# Repeated, unexpected Django Queryset Evaluation

Tags: python, django

I have the following code snippet in a Django integration test:

```
alerts = models.DroppedDom.objects.all()
print 123321, alerts
print 123321, alerts
print 123321, alerts
time.sleep(1)
print 123321, alerts
```

In a separate thread, I am doing a single insert to the DroppedDom table.

Output:

```
123321 []
123321 []
123321 []
123321 [<DroppedDom: DroppedDom object>]
```

Doing a similar thing by hand (no threading) gives the same result.  This implies that every time you print `alerts`, it re-evaluates the query.  I would have expected a single evaluation.

Had I printed `models.DroppedDom.objects.all()` repeatedly instead, I would have expected this result.  But I was floored by the repeated application of the DB query given that I only called `all()` once (I enabled and checked the MySQL logs and found a separate query entry for each print).

Can someone shed light on exactly how this is working?  I am aware of the [Django documentation regarding when querysets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/), but the repeated query evaluation still surprised me.

This is with Django 1.4 and Python 2.6 on Ubuntu 10.04.

FOLLOWUP:

On further investigation, printing the following cause repeated hits to the database:

- `alerts`
- `alerts.exists()`.

The following DO NOT:

- `len(alerts)`
- `bool(alerts)`
- `[a for a in alerts]`

Comment: Repeatedly printing a simple queryset definitely shouldn't cause it to be re-evaluated. Something else is going on here.

Comment: I don't believe there's any difference between calling `.all()` and invoking `alerts`: they're both QuerySets. If true, this would mean the real questions are: (1) once you have exhausted a QuerySet (by looping through it in the `print`), does reinvoking it use the DB cache or does it force a DB query?, and (2) under what conditions does Django invalidate the DB cache (e.g. on the `insert()`)?

Comment: @PeterRowell - right, it is the cache invalidation criteria I don't understand.